# How to force horizontal gap between containers

Tags: css, wordpress, containers

I would like to give defined horizontal gap between three containers. A Gap right and left of the middle container to keep the sections full width. No padding.

Live-view: http://live.bernhard-schrammek.de/#projects

Thank you for help and regards from Berlin

Tibor

Comment: I guess you are seeking vertical gap not horizontal

Comment: Please go read [ask] first of all. All code relevant for your problem belongs directly into your question; see also: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/254428/1427878

Comment: You are right: I am seeking vertical gap. And I will post code directly into my question next time. Sorry and thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add a margin right to each element and cancel it on the last:

```
.item {
   margin-right: 15px;
}

.item:last-child {
   margin-right: 0;
}
```

Or you can just add it to all except the last:

```
.item:nth-last-child(n+2) {
   margin-right: 15px;
}
```

Comment: So simple :-) Thank you, fredrivett

Answer (score 0):

Pertinent to the description, you may use `margin-left` or `margin-right` CSS properties, for example, `margin-left:10px;` (absolute) or `margin-left:1%;` (relative).